# Nlog in hangfire jobs deadlock

Tags: sql, .net-core, deadlock, nlog, hangfire

I am using hangfire as a custom workflow engine in a dotnet core application, which works perfectly fine until I start logging. I log to DB as a requirement. So normal database target. I enabled a sync=true. Once I turn logging on I start getting deadlocks. All is using DI. Again all works fine without log, once I add a rule to write the logs in db I get a deadlock. It’s not even a lot of concurrent jobs, only 11 in my test. Help pls?! Already lost a week on this and still stuck.

I am not sure it’s related, but I am also getting this at the same time: asynchronous exception: timeout flushing all targets

Comment: The exception looks an issue. Please share your config. Do you have throwError enabled in your config? That is not recommend

Comment: Hi @Julian and thanks for replying. I actually found the root cause of this problem and it was a delete sql inside the store procedure that was being executed by log. I am new to stakoverflow, so I am not sure how to "close" this question. Should I answer myself? What should I do? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Ubi! If you think this could useful for others, then answer your own question and mark it as answer. But for this case I think the question is a bit too broad and issue is not really related, so I think delete of your question is better.